# .NET and SOAP tags question (serialization of object into XML)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, soap

quick question: I am working on creating a XML souap envelope that should have this structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSomething>
      <SecurityToken>{{SecurityToken}}</SecurityToken>
      <ID>{{ID}}</ID>
      <StartDate>{{StartDate}}</StartDate>
      <EndDate>{{EndDate}}</EndDate>
    </GetSomething>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have been able to get it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <Body>
        <GetSomething>
          <SecurityToken>{{SecurityToken}}</SecurityToken>
          <ID>{{ID}}</ID>
          <StartDate>{{StartDate}}</StartDate>
          <EndDate>{{EndDate}}</EndDate>
        </GetSomething>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

...but for some reason I can't get it to show the soap: before the body and envelope tags, so the request will not work when sent (the one with the "soap:" tags will when I send it from Postman, but not if I remove them).

Here's how the Envelope class looks:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Some.Namespace
{
    [XmlRoot("Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class GetSomething
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SecurityToken", Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com/")]
        public string SecurityToken { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID", Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com/")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "StartDate", Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com/")]
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EndDate", Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com/")]
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Body
    {
        public Body()
        {
            this.GetSomething = new GetSomething();
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetSomething", Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.org/")]
        public GetSomething GetSomething { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Envelope
    {

        public Envelope()
        {
            this.Body = new Body();
        }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soap { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know hot to generate those soap: tags into my generated XML? I know I could hard code them into a string and add my parameters (ID, Token and dates) but I think it's cleaner to generate the XML from the class. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to generate those soap: tags into my generated
>   XML?

Those `soap:` tags (as you called them) is called `Namespace`. you can create a namespace and then include the `Envelope` and `Body` under this namespace.

Soap has a default namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` You can work with `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` in .NET. in the following example I've used `XDocument` which is my favorite class for XML.

```
//Declare Soap Namespace
XNamespace ns = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

//Create Soap Envelope
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(ns + "Envelope",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", ns),

        new XElement(ns + "Body", 
            new XElement(ns + "GetSomething",
                new XElement("SecurityToken", "{{SecurityToken}}"),
                new XElement("ID", "{{ID}}"),
                new XElement("StartDate", "{{StartDate}}"),
                new XElement("EndDate", "{{EndDate}}")
                )//<GetSomething>
            ) //<soap:Body>
        )//<soap:Envelope>
    );
```

when you combine the namespace in `XElement`, it'll add a prefix to the `XElement` name (tag name). such as `ns + "Envelope"` it'll output `<soap:Envelope>` which means `<Envelope>` element is under `soap` namespace.